# MySql connector j allow user variables

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Please help me to find out how to allow mysql connector j to define user variables and make this code valid:

```
    Statement s = conn.createStatement();
    s.executeQuery ("set @categoryId := (Select CategoryId from categories order by CategoryId desc LIMIT 1);\n" +
                        "set @categoryId := IF(@categoryId is Null, 1, @categoryId);");
```

now it throws an exception:

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException occured : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set @categoryId := IF(@categoryId is Null, 1, @categoryId)' at line 2
```

I know that in .net you can define "Allow User Variables = true" option in connection string. How to do it in java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out how to get it worked. Just set datasource property allowMultiQueries=true

```
 jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBS?allowMultiQueries=true
```